# Hide rows until needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm sure this has been asked before but I'm really struggling with it. I have a database that lists three companies and compares the prices of several products like this:

```
                    Company 1          Company 2           Company 3
Product 1           £                  £                   £

Product 2

Product 3
```

In between each row where a product is listed there is a row which says '*Website link- to be hidden*' and then the different website link to that product is pasted underneath. The idea is that this row should be hidden until needed so it looks like the spreadsheet is just showing price comparisons. Is there any way I can make every other row into some kind of drop-down so you can just click it to show and click it to hide again?

Comment: DOH! well I couldn't have looked much stupider -_- over complicated it for myself haha, thanks so much pnuts, apologies for making you read such a convoluted question for such an easy issue

Answer (score 0):

OP seems to have had a 'senior moment' and the answer is quite simply to apply Filter but for the sake of an answer extensive details are available [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/filter-data-in-an-excel-table-HA102840028.aspx) and a short version:

**Filter by specific text or numbers**

1. Click the arrow  in the table header of the column you want to filter.
2. If the column has numbers, click Number Filters. If the column has text entries, click Text Filters.

In this case with currency and website links mixed in the same column a character such as colon or slash may be suitable for the selection basis.

A similar outsome could be achieved with Subtotal but would be 'fiddly' (quite a lot of layout adjustment to achieve result), though with grouping this may allow more control of what is on view and what hidden at any one time.